# В чем отличие функций c возвратом Void и просто той которая ничего не возвращает. Swift 5

Tags: swift, функции

[image]
Как я понимаю, то отличий вообще нет, в таком случае зачем это Void? Где можно применить и в каких целях использовать? Благодарю, за ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем в [документации](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) касательно функции

```
func greet(person: String) {
    print("Hello, \(person)!")
}
```

> Because it does not need to return a value, the function’s definition
>   does not include the return arrow (->) or a return type.
>
> Note
>
> Strictly speaking, this version of the greet(person:) function does
>   still return a value, even though no return value is defined.
>   Functions without a defined return type return a special value of type
>   Void. This is simply an empty tuple, which is written as ().

То есть строго говоря, такая функция тоже возвращает значение, равное `()` (пустой кортеж), вариант без `-> Void` является таким образом упрощенным вариантом, поэтому никакого особого смысла его добавлять нет.

При этом можно написать

`let r = printHello(text: "Hello")`

Хотя будет предупреждение `warning: constant 'r' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected`